# How to address "Missing argument for parameter 'item' in call" in PreviewProvider for non-custom member variable

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to create a view to represent a CBPerhipheral and am not sure how to deal with the PreviewProvider for a non-custom object. I don't want to make the item nullable, because do need it and it seems like a workaround. The error is:

```
Missing argument for parameter 'item' in call
```

Here is my code:

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreBluetooth

struct PeripheralDetailView: View {
    
    let item: CBPeripheral
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
    }
}

struct PeripheralDetailView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        PeripheralDetailView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a protocol that `CBPeripheral` conforms to, then make your `View` generic over a type that conforms that protocol, e.g.

```
protocol PeripheralType {
    var name: String? { get }
}

extension CBPeripheral: PeripheralType {
    
}

struct PeripheralDetailView<Peripheral: PeripheralType>: View {
    
    let item: Peripheral
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(item.name ?? "")
    }
}
```

To use this in a Preview, declare a mock object that also conforms to the protocol:

```
struct MockPeripheral: PeripheralType {
    let name: String?
}

struct PeripheralDetailView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        PeripheralDetailView(item: MockPeripheral(name: "Headphones"))
    }
}
```